# Hyper-linking in BibTex references

Tags: bibtex, hyperref

I use BibTex library for adding references and for hyperlinking references I use following technique:

```
@article{coggeshall1992group,

  title={\href{http://scitation.aip.org/content/aip/journal/jmp/33/10/10.1063/1.529907}{Group-invariant solutions and optimal systems for multidimensional hydrodynamics}},

  author={Coggeshall, SV and Meyer-ter-Vehn, J},

  journal={Journal of mathematical physics},

  volume={33},

  number={10},

  pages={3585--3601},

  year={1992},

  publisher={AIP Publishing}
}
```

In this way only title of article get blue in bibliography. What should I do so that all items(for e.g. author, year, volume, number, etc) in reference get blue for clicking??

Edit: Please see this [article](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0096300313008965) in which reference style is used which I am talking of.